# MacBook OS X applications crashing on startup

Tags: macos, crash

Closed my computer last night, went home. Opened it and it had restarted.  Now when I open a couple programs such as Adobe Fireworks or Appcelerator Titanium they throw up a nasty error like below.  Other programs (Chrome, Firefox, Textmate, Versions) work fine.

Any thoughts on this?  I haven't owned my MacBook long so I'm not even aware of the right tools or places to look to track this down.  Any help would be most appreciated. It's making it hard to get my work done :]

### If it helps at all both those programs were probably open when it restarted.  From the look of it I'm not sure if it's a permissions error or something?  I completely re-installed one of the applications (Appcelerator Titanium). Didn't seem to help.

---

```
Process:         Adobe Fireworks CS5 [1044]
Path:            /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Fireworks CS5
Identifier:      com.macromedia.fireworks
Version:         Adobe Fireworks CS5 version 11.0.0.484 (11.0.0)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [87]

Date/Time:       2011-02-18 09:45:47.689 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          12983 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           6
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  325365 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4
Anonymous UUID:                      D16EAFE7-2F04-44D4-A984-5902A6EF8943

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000b0327ff8
Crashed Thread:  7

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dd0142 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dd5c46 pthread_mutex_lock + 490
2   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x91887559 __gnu_cxx::__recursive_mutex::lock() + 17
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x918874e6 __cxa_guard_acquire + 68
4   libTrueTypeScaler.dylib         0x91c92ab3 TTScalerInfo() + 50
5   libFontParser.dylib             0x9979a5f1 TTrueTypeScaler::CreateTrueTypeScaler() + 43
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dee900 pthread_once + 82
7   libFontParser.dylib             0x9979a575 TTrueTypeScaler::GetTrueTypeScaler() + 47
8   libFontParser.dylib             0x9979a520 TTrueTypeScaler::TTrueTypeScaler(TScalerStrike const&) + 26
9   libFontParser.dylib             0x9979a4be TFontScaler::CreateFontScaler(TScalerStrike const&) + 52
10  libFontParser.dylib             0x9979bd93 FPFontGetGlyphsForUnichars + 344
11  com.apple.CoreText              0x98255cfe TBaseFont::CalculateFontMetrics(bool) const + 342
12  com.apple.CoreText              0x98255b55 TBaseFont::InitFontMetrics() const + 51
13  com.apple.CoreText              0x98255959 TBaseFont::GetStrikeMetrics(float, CGAffineTransform const*, bool) const + 81
14  com.apple.CoreText              0x982558cd TFont::InitStrikeMetrics() const + 55
15  com.apple.CoreText              0x982592cf CTFontGetAscent + 49
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x989f5d08 __NSFontInstanceInfoInitializeMetricsInfo + 48
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x989f5cbc -[__NSSharedFontInstanceInfo _defaultLineHeight:] + 40
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x98f3c5e8 +[NSStringDrawingTextStorage _fastDrawString:attributes:length:inRect:graphicsContext:baselineRendering:usesFontLeading:usesScreenFont:typesetterBehavior:paragraphStyle:lineBreakMode:boundingRect:padding:scrollable:] + 2041
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x98abd2d9 _NSStringDrawingCore + 1555
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x98abca8b _NSDrawTextCell + 3465
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ac6185 -[NSTextFieldCell drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:] + 764
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ac5d26 -[NSTextFieldCell drawWithFrame:inView:] + 816
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ac03de -[NSControl drawRect:] + 589
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ab882a -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3510
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ab74c8 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1600
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ab77fd -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2421
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ab77fd -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2421
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ab59e7 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 711
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x98b54aa3 -[NSNextStepFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 311
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x98ab1ea2 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 3309
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x98a12a57 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 818
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x989c6661 -[NSNextStepFrame displayIfNeeded] + 98
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x98b55390 -[NSWindow display] + 75
34  com.macromedia.fireworks        0x00bade98 0x1000 + 12242584
35  com.macromedia.fireworks        0x0089f778 0x1000 + 9037688
36  libPowerPlant2.dylib            0x08109722 FW_PowerPlant::LCarbonApp::Run() + 54
37  com.macromedia.fireworks        0x008a138c 0x1000 + 9044876
38  com.macromedia.fireworks        0x00003596 0x1000 + 9622

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df6982 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df709c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df6559 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df62fe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df5d81 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df5bc6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df5a12 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df5fa8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97df5bc6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dd015a semaphore_timedwait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfdce5 _pthread_cond_wait + 1066
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97e2cac8 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97af4ecd TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 242
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97af4c0b TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 511
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97b18e33 TimerThread + 97
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd85d _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dd00fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dd0867 mach_msg + 68
2   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97b9e0d0 YieldToThread + 446
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97b9e1d3 SetThreadState + 134
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97b9e28e SetThreadStateEndCritical + 111
5   libPowerPlant2.dylib            0x0811ab51 FW_PowerPlant::LThread::SemWait(FW_PowerPlant::LSemaphore*, long, QHdr&, unsigned char&) + 119
6   libPowerPlant2.dylib            0x08119b07 FW_PowerPlant::LSemaphore::BlockThread(long) + 61
7   libPowerPlant2.dylib            0x08119b6d FW_PowerPlant::LSemaphore::Wait(long) + 71
8   libPowerPlant2.dylib            0x0811af70 FW_PowerPlant::LThread::Cleanup::Run() + 32
9   libPowerPlant2.dylib            0x0811b94e FW_PowerPlant::LThread::DoEntry(void*) + 30
10  ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97b9e85f CooperativeThread + 309
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd85d _pthread_start + 345
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dd0142 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfdcfc _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97e4646f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.adobe.amt.services          0x1dd73126 AMTConditionLock::LockWhenCondition(int) + 46
4   com.adobe.amt.services          0x1dd6bdb0 _AMTThreadedPCDService::PCDThreadWorker(_AMTThreadedPCDService*) + 116
5   com.adobe.amt.services          0x1dd7318c AMTThread::Worker(void*) + 24
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd85d _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfe0a6 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfdd62 _pthread_cond_wait + 1191
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dff9f8 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 73
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97b0951e TSWaitOnCondition + 126
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97af4ea5 TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 202
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97af0873 MPWaitOnQueue + 250
6   com.macromedia.fireworks        0x00ae43cf 0x1000 + 11416527
7   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x97ad485a PrivateMPEntryPoint + 68
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd85d _pthread_start + 345
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x9184e00c std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) + 16
1   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x9184fe9b std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) + 211
2   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e824779 ESDifstream::ESDifstream(std::string const&, char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) + 73
3   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e821b6a esd::ExpatDOMBuilder<esd::XMLDocumentNode>::ParseFile(std::string const&, bool) + 96
4   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e822da4 esd::PrefsWriter::SetPrefsPath(std::string const&) + 206
5   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e8449b3 AdobeUpdaterPrefs::AdobeUpdaterPrefs() + 8609
6   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e8459f4 AdobeUpdaterPrefs::GetAdobeUpdaterPrefs() + 68
7   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e820728 UpdaterNotificationsImpl::InitLogFile() + 48
8   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e820d49 UpdaterNotificationsImpl::Instance() + 53
9   ...pdaterNotificationFramework  0x1e823638 UpdaterNotificationsIsUpdaterEnabled + 22
10  com.adobe.amt.services          0x1dd69d15 _AMTAUMService::IsUpdaterEnabled(T_CSUStatusMajor*, int*) + 359
11  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f5501c AMTAUMServiceIsUpdaterEnabled + 290
12  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f1f789 AMTImpl::CallMenuEnablers() + 71
13  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f260fa AMTImpl::DoLaunchWorkflow(AMTImpl::LaunchSequence) + 1664
14  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f26a5d AMTImpl::DoValidateWorkflow(AMTImpl::LaunchSequence) + 293
15  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f26cf5 AMTImpl::DoPreValidateWorkflow() + 119
16  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f26e71 AMTImpl::ServiceLoaderThread(void*) + 45
17  com.adobe.amtlib                0x01f54c48 AMTThread::Worker(void*) + 24
18  libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd85d _pthread_start + 345
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x97dfd6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 7 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000016  ebx: 0x098c9a00  ecx: 0xa013dfc0  edx: 0x00000003
  edi: 0x098c9a08  esi: 0x098c9c0c  ebp: 0xb03a7448  esp: 0xb0327ff0
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x9184e00c   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0xb0327ff8

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -  0x1448ff1 +com.macromedia.fireworks Adobe Fireworks CS5 version 11.0.0.484 (11.0.0) <38213EBD-FDB0-FC20-40E8-87935A5386BB> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Fireworks CS5
 0x1e76000 -  0x1ec9ffb +com.adobe.headlights.LogSessionFramework ??? (2.0.1.011) <4F2BFF03-01D2-A07D-E5E2-7F88D4C2DEC4> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/LogSession.framework/Versions/A/LogSession
 0x1f11000 -  0x1f77ffb +com.adobe.amtlib amtlib 3.0.0.64 (3.0.0.64) <DD471011-9120-1BC2-F1B5-D6FF09D0859F> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/amtlib.framework/Versions/A/amtlib
 0x1fa7000 -  0x2146fe7 +com.adobe.owl AdobeOwl version 3.0.81 (3.0.81) <9C261D9E-9BD7-5DE6-5676-AEEF4828D17B> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeOwl.framework/Versions/A/AdobeOwl
 0x21af000 -  0x22e7fe7 +WRServices ??? (???) <52CE5B97-1E6A-92A2-EA70-93511AB7EA2E> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/WRServices.framework/Versions/A/WRServices
 0x232d000 -  0x239afef +FileInfo ??? (???) <4A4C74F9-CA83-B174-F56D-F7671DC61389> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/FileInfo.framework/Versions/A/FileInfo
 0x23b5000 -  0x23dbff6 +AdobeAXE8SharedExpat ??? (???) <5848BBCE-3A3E-66EE-5527-97A96F0CA4CC> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeAXE8SharedExpat.framework/Versions/A/AdobeAXE8SharedExpat
 0x23ec000 -  0x2407fff +AdobeBIB ??? (???) <3B3092DC-A296-9D1C-1922-D20E6A5A7D7E> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeBIB.framework/Versions/A/AdobeBIB
 0x2411000 -  0x2469ff7 +AdobeXMP ??? (???) <73329999-C364-2451-6574-4D0277057D19> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeXMP.framework/Versions/A/AdobeXMP
 0x2478000 -  0x2aa6fe7 +AdobeAGM ??? (???) <91D37E54-E985-47E1-2696-0BD7E4183132> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeAGM.framework/Versions/A/AdobeAGM
 0x2c04000 -  0x2d18fff +AdobeACE ??? (???) <DD291A17-ECF4-FE20-5837-AC1F5BC76940> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeACE.framework/Versions/A/AdobeACE
 0x2d3b000 -  0x302dff7 +AdobeCoolType ??? (???) <9FDD596D-9824-2BB9-5DA2-25DACAB6A324> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeCoolType.framework/Versions/A/AdobeCoolType
 0x30b5000 -  0x30d6ff7 +AdobeBIBUtils ??? (???) <E1FAA7A3-E807-DE5A-1F68-7A53780E8202> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeBIBUtils.framework/Versions/A/AdobeBIBUtils
 0x30e2000 -  0x311efff +AdobeARE ??? (???) <76851E91-2381-5D05-742C-BB24E4BAD276> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeARE.framework/Versions/A/AdobeARE
 0x3127000 -  0x34ffff7 +AdobeMPS ??? (???) <13614867-4D80-EB74-FA7F-6136492478BA> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeMPS.framework/Versions/A/AdobeMPS
 0x362e000 -  0x3c62feb +AdobePDFL ??? (???) <49D6D58A-1EBB-424A-4CB0-8F9691E0991D> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobePDFL.framework/Versions/A/AdobePDFL
 0x3d8e000 -  0x4ad1fff +com.adobe.psl AdobePSL 12.0.0.7524 (12.0.0.7524) <CFBCB19A-03F7-D095-1F48-8D68F05A25C5> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobePSL.framework/Versions/A/AdobePSL
 0x4e10000 -  0x4e9aff7 +com.adobe.AdobeScCore ScCore 4.1.7 (4.1.7.5522) <053A109E-3E3E-D3EE-7186-4920D927D2AD> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeScCore.framework/Versions/A/AdobeScCore
 0x4edd000 -  0x4fc0fef +AdobePDFPort ??? (???) <A2E6DCF7-283F-09E9-53AE-D5D84D020469> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobePDFPort.framework/Versions/A/AdobePDFPort
 0x4ff5000 -  0x4ff8ff8 +com.adobe.ape.shim adbeape version 3.1.65.7508 (3.1.65.7508) <FFDDAB7A-220F-7344-F12B-010CA0C41DAB> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/adbeape.framework/Versions/A/adbeape
 0x4ffe000 -  0x508fff7 +libicucnv.dylib.36.0 36.0.0 (compatibility 36.0.0) <581475CC-C039-1B42-49BA-71811D8B4E15> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUConverter.framework/Versions/3.6/libicucnv.dylib.36.0
 0x50ae000 -  0x5a5efff +libicudata.dylib.36.0 36.0.0 (compatibility 36.0.0) <02108DEA-3DD2-14BE-DAEB-BE522B619C1D> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUData.framework/Versions/3.6/libicudata.dylib.36.0
 0x5a61000 -  0x5b2eff3 +libicui18n.dylib.36.0 36.0.0 (compatibility 36.0.0) <08F15219-7F35-574E-7725-1ACAA1B18A00> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUInternationalization.framework/Versions/3.6/libicui18n.dylib.36.0
 0x5b91000 -  0x5c6bfef +libicuuc.dylib.36.0 36.0.0 (compatibility 36.0.0) <5EE72009-40B3-7FB7-3A49-576AEDE0D400> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ICUUnicode.framework/Versions/3.6/libicuuc.dylib.36.0
 0x5cab000 -  0x6a36fe7 +com.adobe.illustrator 382 (15.0.0) <64F68532-0311-6BBA-1F50-246CAF917549> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AILib.framework/Versions/A/AILib
 0x781b000 -  0x785ffff +com.adobe.illustrator.aiport AIPort version 1.0 (1.0) <69EDC44E-D7BB-A259-282D-C42725AE0E26> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AIPort.framework/Versions/A/AIPort
 0x78c2000 -  0x7908fff +FilterPort ??? (???) <23FAE9D1-9376-1E71-21F7-D3EB2BFD50EE> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/FilterPort.framework/Versions/A/FilterPort
 0x797d000 -  0x797dfff +SPBasic ??? (???) <5D1760D8-C910-C641-0BC9-CF74A1A5190D> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/SPBasic.framework/Versions/A/SPBasic
 0x7981000 -  0x7b67ff7 +com.adobe.linguistic.LinguisticManager 5.0.0 (11309) <CA1D50A3-F965-F8B2-76B9-007F290C5791> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeLinguistic.framework/Versions/3/AdobeLinguistic
 0x7bf5000 -  0x7cc2fe7 +AdobeAXEDOMCore ??? (???) <F76D74DC-FD5A-9783-C447-2E58773DA7E1> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeAXEDOMCore.framework/Versions/A/AdobeAXEDOMCore
 0x7d31000 -  0x7ea9ffb +com.adobe.PlugPlug 2.0.0.746 (2.0.0.746) <08AD22E3-34C0-6749-E497-616C66A246AD> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/PlugPlug.framework/Versions/A/PlugPlug
 0x7f4d000 -  0x7f6afef +libCurl.dylib ??? (???) <1BA6E2DE-EF14-D50A-4697-035AE07875D7> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/libCurl.dylib
 0x7f72000 -  0x7f88ff4 +libChar16.dylib ??? (???) <19B0479C-72B1-EE14-6385-7F655DEC0F02> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/libChar16.dylib
 0x7f90000 -  0x7fb3fe0 +libCoreTypes.dylib ??? (???) <F5306147-FFBD-2826-D356-B26258DBFA09> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/libCoreTypes.dylib
 0x7fc3000 -  0x7fcaffc  com.apple.carbonframeworktemplate 1.0 (1.0) <0D270CC7-B715-943E-2B4F-5C9B5775505A> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/NetIO.framework/Versions/A/NetIO
 0x7fd6000 -  0x7fd9fff +Dioxide.dylib ??? (???) <BCE94F23-4CCA-20FB-79A8-DE7925879DCD> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/Dioxide.dylib
 0x7fe1000 -  0x7fe7ffc +libfwutility.dylib ??? (???) <6A723D9E-A60B-56EE-2B8D-B91991793749> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/libfwutility.dylib
 0x7fee000 -  0x803efff +com.macromedia.javascript Javascript version 1.0 (1.0) <540CB029-3946-8E41-BD91-AED6F73C86B7> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/Javascript.framework/Versions/A/Javascript
 0x8053000 -  0x8060fff +com.macromedia.moa Moa version 1.0 (1.0) <3C4B7F42-5A5D-78E7-B1DC-DAA06A99CCB2> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/Moa.framework/Versions/A/Moa
 0x8069000 -  0x8070fff +com.macromedia.morefiles MoreFiles version 1.0 (1.0) <36115C66-79A3-5DB9-B36B-8D655B46FC76> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/MoreFiles.framework/Versions/A/MoreFiles
 0x8077000 -  0x815bfe3 +libPowerPlant2.dylib ??? (???) <964FB3D7-B7EE-94EB-FD95-4AE90C657A4A> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/libPowerPlant2.dylib
 0x828e000 -  0x8294ffb +com.macromedia.testframework 1.0 (1.0) <ED14FA00-1C6F-D433-1EEB-833BB4402B2B> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/uwchar.framework/Versions/A/uwchar
 0x8298000 -  0x829cffc +com.adobe.AdobeCrashReporter 3.0 (3.0.20100302) <E6437929-0E69-8A56-E69F-F64305E82DD9> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeCrashReporter.framework/Versions/A/AdobeCrashReporter
 0x82a3000 -  0x82bbfef +libgiff.dylib ??? (???) <8F90552B-3D11-2B1E-D1BA-A109FEB99969> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgiff.dylib
 0x82c3000 -  0x82e1fe7 +com.macromedia.png LibPNG version 1.0 (1.0) <2DBA0A3F-4F01-7474-0FED-3021382D635F> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/LibPNG.framework/Versions/A/LibPNG
 0x82e9000 -  0x82f7feb +com.macromedia.zlib ZLib version 1.0 (1.0) <EEA4CFAF-A748-FA72-91F0-ADE7A1BE9FA7> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ZLib.framework/Versions/A/ZLib
 0x82fc000 -  0x8300ffd +com.yourcompany.yourcocoaframework ??? (1.0) <7EF7A82E-0AAE-0022-3B15-7C50F1C550C1> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ASEFramework.framework/Versions/A/ASEFramework
 0x8305000 -  0x830cff2 +com.adobe.boost_threads.framework boost_threads version 5.0.0 (5.0.0.0) <F966C78A-3CC1-8678-B3B7-B0A2B118343A> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/boost_threads.framework/Versions/A/boost_threads
 0x831c000 -  0x8322fef +com.adobe.boost_date_time.framework boost_date_time version 5.0.0 (5.0.0.0) <8837A972-1EBE-CAA9-473A-CD157F17163D> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/boost_date_time.framework/Versions/A/boost_date_time
 0x8333000 -  0x83b0fff +AdobeOwlCanvas ??? (???) <65B2E680-4F43-BE46-2290-3500758D1BF7> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdobeOwlCanvas.framework/Versions/A/AdobeOwlCanvas
 0x83cc000 -  0x83d7ff3 +com.adobe.boost_filesystem.framework boost_filesystem version 5.0.0 (5.0.0.0) <90B8B4E3-6C44-D110-1545-1A34EB14B22D> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/boost_filesystem.framework/Versions/A/boost_filesystem
 0x83eb000 -  0x83edffb +com.adobe.boost_system.framework boost_system version 5.0.0 (5.0.0.0) <0C4D56E8-9593-4C4A-4A7E-BEAEDE1CA131> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/boost_system.framework/Versions/A/boost_system

...

E86745B94A4B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x9984a000 - 0x9989aff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <AF7F86F1-F7BF-CBA8-7A4A-D8F7A19F9601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x99a6e000 - 0x99a6fff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <BE4C2495-B758-AD22-DCC0-56A6791E948E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x99a72000 - 0x99a86ffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <9F5CE4F7-D05C-8C14-4B76-E43D07A8A680> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0xb0000000 - 0xb000fff8 +com.adobe.ahclientframework 1.5.0.30 (1.5.0.30) <24B39C2F-79B0-BDE3-C6D0-1F0E943070C7> /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/Frameworks/ahclient.framework/Versions/A/ahclient
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <62291026-D016-705D-DC1E-FC2B09D47DE5> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

---

If you prefer, Here are the crashes on Pastebin:

[Crash 1 (Fireworks)](http://pastebin.com/LEp2W8du)
[Crash 2 (Appcelerator Titanium)](http://pastebin.com/HDePjgWi)

Comment: …Or formatting them.

Comment: I have now tried the 'repair permissions' using the disk utility.  That didn't seem to do anything.  I'll look at Pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LEp2W8du

Comment: Here is the other app that I noticed it happening with: http://pastebin.com/HDePjgWi

Comment: This is happening with two applications that I can tell, I opened up a bunch of others to test and don't seem to be getting it.  I have uninstalled / reinstalled apps, deleted preference files and files/folders the apps have installed.  I've run applejack, rember... run disk utilities. I've tried making another user account and trying the apps on that account. All still crashing.  :[    Possibly re-install OS X but that doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Comment: TL/DNR... random idea: check your RAM!

Comment: @Ryan Doom could you start the applications from the command line? Sometimes there is a better error description, if the programs aborts to run. Just start them in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but both crashed in libstdc++, apparently in STL classes. Maybe that library got corrupted, so any app that uses C++ and touches the corrupt part of the library will crash. Maybe your apps that are NOT crashing are completely Obj-C based, or maybe use C++ but don't use those STL classes.

Short of reinstalling the OS, you could try copying over a good version of `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib` from another 10.6.6 machine.

On my 10.6.6 machine, here's the MD5 for that file:

```
$ md5 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
MD5 (/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib) = 47476e8c6499f483525e07c015310183
```

Check the MD5 of that file on your machine and see if it matches or not.

Comment: a4d07340212e0cb8cd89b5d0c12347cc is working on 10.6.7

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearcut but the fact that it panicked and restarted, plus applications crashing due to memory violations points to a memory problem (physical). Possibly, one of the memory modules have come loose slightly during the travel. I would remove and reset them as a first step.

Comment: I just ran rember on it, took 45 minutes but reported that all memory passed. So, I assume if it's able to use / test all 4gb of memory that it is probably seated physically.

Comment: Keep in mind that Rember can only test memory it can allocate, and since the kernel needs to keep some memory for itself, it's doubtful that Rember was able to test _all_ your memory. I'd suggest running the [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) as well - it isn't as thorough as Rember, but it might find problems in places Rember wasn't able to check. But the AHT also has its limitations: AFAIK, most memory testing programs can't test the memory used by themselves, and though I'm guessing there are ways to handle this, I don't know if either AHT or Rember implement them.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing when it tries to load your adobe preferences from a file, which implies that the file is corrupted. Your best bet is to find the preferences file and remove it.

1. Close all of your programs.
2. Go into /Library/Preferences
3. Use spotlight to search for all preference files with "Adobe" in the name.
4. Drag those files to the trash.
5. Go into /Users/**your username**/Library/Preference
6. Use spotlight to search for all preference files with "Adobe" in the name.
7. Drag those files to the trash.
8. Empty the trash
9. Try opening fireworks again.

Comment: No need to get rid of preferences files (step 8) without knowing if that's actually the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reinstalling the OS; one of the OS files must have been corrupted or locked.

With OS X you can reinstall the OS without affecting any of your apps or data, so it only took about 30 minutes to reinstall and fix everything.